# fullcalendar not working with primary google calendar

Tags: fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I am trying to use fullcalendar with my google calendar. Unfortunately, I am unable to connect it with my primary calendar. But I am able to connect it to a second calendar (which is not my primary calendar). I am clueless as to why that would be the case. And yes, both calendars are public.

In order to eliminate any problem on the coding side, I have been using the demo-google calendar page which comes with fullcalendar.io and I have simply replaced the API and the googleCalendarID. 
Feel free to give this a shot yourself. The ID of my primary calendar is: "nms@hsneumarkt.at" and the secondary calendar is "g0i3ccm1sse6atvasvgilsafkk@group.calendar.google.com" Both calendars have the same content.

One more thing to consider here. I also created a jsfiddle and I can get both calendars to work there. See: http://jsfiddle.net/58ayq9xL/3/
The only difference between the jsfiddle and the local fullcalendar.io is the version. Whereas locally I am using 3.9, the jsfiddle is using 2.3.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        googleCalendarApiKey: 'myAPI',
        events: {
            googleCalendarId: 'my@calendarID.com'
        }
    });
});
```

I also had a friend try it on his personally website and he cannot load the primary calendar with the 3.9 version either.

What could be the cause of this issue? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: code - need to show what you have done

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I edited my original post to clarify that I have been using the demo-page in order to eliminate any coding error on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

So it turns out that the demo-page had the Calendar ID inserted like this:

```
events: 'my@calendarID.com'
```

But on the jsfiddle I included it like this:

```
events: {
      googleCalendarId: 'my@calendarID.com'
}
```

For reasons which are beyond my understanding the demo-calendar still worked as long as I loaded a secondary calendar. As soon as I loaded my primary Google calendar it couldn't load the events.

I don't know if the fullcalendar.io creator will ever read this, but it might be a good idea to adapt the code in the demo page.